# Can I install Ubuntu 64 bit alongside a Windows 8.1 32 bit pc?

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit

UEFI is not enabled in my PC so Windows 8.1 was installed in Legacy Mode and I was wondering I could dual-boot 64 bit version of Ubuntu with Windows 8.1 32 bit PC without any problems? Also if it is possible please tell me the exact steps to properly install Ubuntu.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's no problem at all. Install the 64 bit version of Ubuntu. The two systems are independent of each other.

Grab a USB stick (2 GB will do) and look for a program which is able to get the content of the image file onto it. If your PC doesn't boot from the USB stick look for boot order in your bios settings and move booting from USB up to the top. You will be guided through the installation process.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that I dont really have a modern PC. Its an old PC with 2 GB ram and a Pentium E5400 @2.70ghz Dual core. Have not ever updated the bios but I can properly boot to USB disks. Will not updating the bios can cause any hiccups? Sorry if I am asking too many questions but its not really first time installing operating systems though never installed linux and I need it for compiling android.

Comment: I can't say anything about your processor but 2 GB of ram are sufficient. Make sure to have 6 or 7 GB or swap though. Updating your bios comes with a risk. Look at the changes and update it if there are improvements or there currently are problems which you want to be solved or if you want to avoid possible future problems and therefore take the risk quick and easy and not stretched out over an extended period of time. The latter reason is why I keep my bios updated. However, you won't be able to install Ubuntu any better or worse if you do than if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the directions properly. This will work fine, but depending on your bios, there could be a few hiccups.

Install windows first in legacy, and then Ubuntu. The 32bit vs 64bit shouldn't matter since it's OS and kernel specific.

Here is the documentation:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot